# How to set a GMSCameraPosition from a bounds

Tags: swift, swiftui, google-maps-sdk-ios

I have a list of coordinates that I would like to be visible on my Google Map.

For MapKit, I can create a `MKCoordinateRegion` that would include all my coordinates and then set my app to that region.

Google Maps uses an `GMSCameraPosition` that takes a coordinate and a zoom level. I'm not understanding out to set this to a specific region on the map.

I tried creating a bounds like this and updating the camera but nothing happens.

```
let bounds = GMSCoordinateBounds()
for coordinate in coordinates {
    bounds.includingCoordinate(coordinate)
}

let update = GMSCameraUpdate.fit(bounds)
mapView.moveCamera(update)
```

I'm wrapping my Google Maps view in a `UIViewRepresentable` for SwiftUI and ideally I would like to make the camera update from my list of coordinates just by changing the camera position. Is there a way to make a `GMSCameraPosition` from a `GMSCoordinateBounds`?

Answer (score 0):

As per documentation, GMSCoordinateBounds can't be mutated.
You should add bounds like below

```
var bounds = GMSCoordinateBounds()
for coordinate in coordinates {
    bounds = bounds.includingCoordinate(coordinate)
}
```